# Velocity.js/Blast.js starting opacity at 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2, velocity.js

I am using Velocity.js and Blast.js to create a simple load in each word as an animation... one of the basic setups. I am also using this alongside Cycle2.

I have a few issues with what I am trying to achieve that I cannot work out from the documentation. A 'Velocity/Blast function' can exist on many slides throughout in a cycle2 slider so it needs to re-run each time.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

1. The Velocity animation needs to begin at opacity:0 each time... so when you cycle to a slide it runs from 0 to 1 rather than showing it, then hiding it, then running the animation.
2. As you cycle the slider next/prev it should rerun and start from 0 as before.
3. Remove in transition/fade on each word and simply have it as a show/hide.

I hope this makes sense. I have created a bare bones JSFiddle to show you a basic set up and what I have so far. Hope you can help.

http://jsfiddle.net/h3vo8LL1/1/

```
//
function featuredProjectTextAnimation() {
    $('.home-section-container .each-section .each-slide.text .text-container.animated')
    .blast({ 
        delimiter: 'word' 
    })
    .velocity('transition.fadeIn', {
        display: null,
        duration: 0,
        stagger: 100,
        delay: 400,
        begin: function() { 
            //
        },
        complete: function() { 
            //
        }
    });
}

//
if ($('.home-slider-container').length > 0) {
    $('.home-slider-container .home-slider').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var slideCount = $this.find('.each-slide').length;
        if (slideCount <= 1) {
            $this.next('.home-slider-pager').remove();
            $this.prev('.home-slider-navigation').remove();
        }
        $this.cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            slides: '> .each-slide',
            caption: $this.next('.home-slider-pager'),
            captionTemplate: '{{slideNum}}/{{slideCount}}',
            sync: true,
            timeout: 0,
            random: false,
            pagerActiveClass: 'active',
            next: $this.prev('.home-slider-navigation').find('.next'),
            prev: $this.prev('.home-slider-navigation').find('.prev'),
            loader: true,
            autoHeight: 'container',
            swipe: true
        });
        $this.on('cycle-before', function() {

        });
        $this.on('cycle-after', function() {
            featuredProjectTextAnimation();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/h3vo8LL1/2/ .
You had 2 issues there:

1. You need to pass the incoming slide element to `featuredProjectTextAnimation()` and find the `.animated` element in it, instead of selecting *all* of your text slides.
2. You need to have each slide initially hidden, here, just for example, I set `opacity` to 0 on the outgoing slide element, and on `begin` I set it to 1. You can also use `display: none` or whatever suits you.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked a treat. One final thing, I am also using fullpage.js, so sometimes a text slide might be the first slide, so is it possible to do the same thing on sliding down? I have set up a JSFiddle, using your new code, but adding the fullpage, so if you scroll down I've made the second section start with text but it doesn't animate or show. I've also added in onLeave and afterLoad callbacks for you to use if that helps? http://jsfiddle.net/h3vo8LL1/3/

Comment: Hey, that's against the rules (: You ask a question, if it's solved, accept it. If you want to ask another regarding fullpage, that's a whole different question

Comment: Sorry... you're right. Fancy helping me on the other issue?

Comment: Thanks! Please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664645/velocity-js-blast-js-triggering-using-fullpage-js

Comment: There is a bounty on this now too if that helps?

Comment: Any thoughts? Bounty has expired now.