# Velocity.js/Blast.js triggering using fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, velocity.js

Following on from a solution posted here: [Velocity.js/Blast.js starting opacity at 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614890/velocity-js-blast-js-starting-opacity-at-0/)

I am using Velocity.js and Blast.js to create a simple load in each word as an animation... one of the basic setups. I am also using this alongside Cycle2. I am also using fullpage.js, so sometimes a text slide might be the first slide, so is it possible to do the same thing on sliding down?

1. If the text slide, with the animation, is also the first slide, to trigger the animation from opacity:0 just as it does if you navigate prev/next.

I have set up a JSFiddle, adding the fullpage.js, so if you scroll down I've made the second section start with text but it doesn't animate or show. I've also added in onLeave and afterLoad callbacks for you to use if that helps? [jsfiddle.net/h3vo8LL1/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/h3vo8LL1/4)

```
//
if ($('.home-section-container').length > 0) {
    $('.home-section-container').fullpage({
        sectionSelector: '.each-section',
        scrollingSpeed: 1000,
        resize: false,
        onLeave: function () {
            //
        },
        afterLoad: function () {
            //
        }
    });
}

//
function featuredProjectTextAnimation(incomingSlideEl) {
    var $animated = $(incomingSlideEl).find('.text-container.animated');
    $animated.blast({
        delimiter: 'word'
    })
        .velocity('transition.fadeIn', {
        display: null,
        duration: 0,
        stagger: 100,
        delay: 400,
        begin: function () {
            $animated.css('opacity', 1);
        },
        complete: function () {
            //
        }
    });
}

//
if ($('.home-slider-container').length > 0) {
    $('.home-slider-container .home-slider').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var slideCount = $this.find('.each-slide').length;
        if (slideCount <= 1) {
            $this.next('.home-slider-pager').remove();
            $this.prev('.home-slider-navigation').remove();
        }
        $this.cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            slides: '> .each-slide',
            caption: $this.next('.home-slider-pager'),
            captionTemplate: '{{slideNum}}/{{slideCount}}',
            sync: true,
            timeout: 0,
            random: false,
            pagerActiveClass: 'active',
            next: $this.prev('.home-slider-navigation').find('.next'),
            prev: $this.prev('.home-slider-navigation').find('.prev'),
            loader: true,
            autoHeight: 'container',
            swipe: true
        });
        $this.on('cycle-before', function () {

        });
        $this.on('cycle-after', function (event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl) {
            featuredProjectTextAnimation(incomingSlideEl);
            $(outgoingSlideEl).find('.text-container.animated').css('opacity', 0);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Regarding the bounty. I have updated the JSfiddle. You can see that on the first 'section' the animated text slide in second and as you slide into it, it all works. But on the second 'section' if you scroll down the animated text slide is first and thus doesn't trigger. I know I need to use the onLeave and afterLoad functions but getting stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions#my-other-plugins-dont-work-when-using-fullpagejs):

> **My other plugins don't work when using fullPage.js**
>
> **Short answer:** initialize them in the afterRender callback of fullPage.js.
>
> **Explanation:** if you are using options such as verticalCentered:true or overflowScroll:true of fullPage.js, your
> content will be wrapped inside other elements changing its position in
> the DOM structure of the site. This way, your content would be
> consider as "dynamically added content" and most plugins need the
> content to be originally on the site to perform their tasks. Using the
> afterRender callback to initialize your plugins, fullPage.js makes
> sure to initialize them only when fullPage.js has stopped changing the
> DOM structure of the site.

In any case, you should be using the callbacks provided by fullPage.js to fire your actions, such as `onLeave`, `afterLoad` or `afterSlideLoad`.
The way you are doing it seems not to be the way to go for it...

You should be doing something of this kind:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
        var loadedSection = $(this);

        //after section 2 has loaded
        if (index == 2) {
            fireAnimation();
        }
    },
    afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
        //second slide of the second section
        if (index == 2 && slideIndex == 2) {
            fireAnimation2();
        }
    }
});
```